# How to open maps Application from InAppWebView - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-urls, flutter-inappwebview

I am opening a website using the Flutter InAppWebView.

```
           child: InAppWebView(
                  initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                    url: Uri.parse("https://mywebsite.com"),
                  ),
                  androidOnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt:
                      (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin) async {
                    return GeolocationPermissionShowPromptResponse(
                        origin: origin,
                        allow: true,
                        retain: true
                    );
                  },
                  initialOptions: options,
                  onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                    _webViewController = controller;
                  },
                  androidOnPermissionRequest: (InAppWebViewController controller, String origin, List<String> resources) async {
                    return PermissionRequestResponse(resources: resources, action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
                  }
              ),
```

This website calls a URL:[https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude'](https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=$latitude,$longitude%27) on button click.

This doesn't open the Application and rather continues in the InAppWebView.
How do I resolve this?

Comment: Have you figured it out? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Sadly no @ApurvaAgrawal, I had to do some workaround tweak to the UI.